# Calculate the mean by group

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I have a large data frame that looks similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(dive = factor(sample(c("dive1","dive2"), 10, replace=TRUE)),
                 speed = runif(10)
                 )
> df
    dive      speed
1  dive1 0.80668490
2  dive1 0.53349584
3  dive2 0.07571784
4  dive2 0.39518628
5  dive1 0.84557955
6  dive1 0.69121443
7  dive1 0.38124950
8  dive2 0.22536126
9  dive1 0.04704750
10 dive2 0.93561651
```

My goal is to obtain the average of values in one column when another column is equal to a certain value and repeat this for all values. i.e. in the example above I would like to return an average for the column `speed` for every unique value of the column `dive`. So when `dive==dive1`, the average for `speed` is this and so on for each value of `dive`.

Comment: Related question on how to split-apply-combine but keep the results on the original frame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467219/calculate-group-characteristics-without-ddply-and-merge#comment21890299_15467219

Answer (score 181, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in R.  Specifically, `by`, `aggregate`, `split`, and `plyr`, `cast`, `tapply`, `data.table`, `dplyr`, and so forth.

Broadly speaking, these problems are of the form split-apply-combine.  Hadley Wickham has written a [beautiful article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) that will give you deeper insight into the whole category of problems, and it is well worth reading.  His `plyr` package implements the strategy for general data structures, and `dplyr` is a newer implementation performance tuned for data frames. They allow for solving problems of the same form but of even greater complexity than this one.  They are well worth learning as a general tool for solving data manipulation problems.

Performance is an issue on very large datasets, and for that it is hard to beat solutions based on `data.table`.  If you only deal with medium-sized datasets or smaller, however, taking the time to learn `data.table` is likely not worth the effort. `dplyr` can also be fast, so it is a good choice if you want to speed things up, but don't quite need the scalability of `data.table`.

Many of the other solutions below do not require any additional packages.  Some of them are even fairly fast on medium-large datasets.  Their primary disadvantage is either one of metaphor or of flexibility.  By metaphor I mean that it is a tool designed for something else being coerced to solve this particular type of problem in a 'clever' way.  By flexibility I mean they lack the ability to solve as wide a range of similar problems or to easily produce tidy output.

---

### Examples

#### `base` functions

**`tapply`:**

```
tapply(df$speed, df$dive, mean)
#     dive1     dive2 
# 0.5419921 0.5103974
```

**`aggregate`**:

`aggregate` takes in data.frames, outputs data.frames, and uses a formula interface.

```
aggregate( speed ~ dive, df, mean )
#    dive     speed
# 1 dive1 0.5790946
# 2 dive2 0.4864489
```

**`by`**:

In its most user-friendly form, it takes in vectors and applies a function to them. However, its output is not in a very manipulable form.:

```
res.by <- by(df$speed, df$dive, mean)
res.by
# df$dive: dive1
# [1] 0.5790946
# ---------------------------------------
# df$dive: dive2
# [1] 0.4864489
```

To get around this, for simple uses of `by` the `as.data.frame` method in the `taRifx` library works:

```
library(taRifx)
as.data.frame(res.by)
#    IDX1     value
# 1 dive1 0.6736807
# 2 dive2 0.4051447
```

**`split`**:

As the name suggests, it performs only the "split" part of the split-apply-combine strategy.  To make the rest work, I'll write a small function that uses `sapply` for apply-combine.  `sapply` automatically simplifies the result as much as possible.  In our case, that means a vector rather than a data.frame, since we've got only 1 dimension of results.

```
splitmean <- function(df) {
  s <- split( df, df$dive)
  sapply( s, function(x) mean(x$speed) )
}
splitmean(df)
#     dive1     dive2 
# 0.5790946 0.4864489
```

---

#### External packages

**data.table**:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .(mean_speed = mean(speed)), by = dive]
#    dive mean_speed
# 1: dive1  0.5419921
# 2: dive2  0.5103974
```

**`dplyr`**:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, dive) %>% summarize(m = mean(speed))
```

**`plyr`** (the pre-cursor of `dplyr`)

Here's what the [official page](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) has to say about `plyr`:

> It’s already possible to do this with `base` R functions (like `split` and
>   the `apply` family of functions), but `plyr` makes it all a bit easier
>   with:
>
> - totally consistent names, arguments and outputs
> - convenient parallelisation through the `foreach` package
> - input from and output to data.frames, matrices and lists
> - progress bars to keep track of long running operations
> - built-in error recovery, and informative error messages
> - labels that are maintained across all transformations

In other words, if you learn one tool for split-apply-combine manipulation it should be `plyr`.

```
library(plyr)
res.plyr <- ddply( df, .(dive), function(x) mean(x$speed) )
res.plyr
#    dive        V1
# 1 dive1 0.5790946
# 2 dive2 0.4864489
```

**reshape2**:

The `reshape2` library is not designed with split-apply-combine as its primary focus.  Instead, it uses a two-part melt/cast strategy to perfor[m a wide variety of data reshaping tasks](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper).  However, since it allows an aggregation function it can be used for this problem.  It would not be my first choice for split-apply-combine operations, but its reshaping capabilities are powerful and thus you should learn this package as well.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast( melt(df), variable ~ dive, mean)
# Using dive as id variables
#   variable     dive1     dive2
# 1    speed 0.5790946 0.4864489
```

---

### Benchmarks

#### 10 rows, 2 groups

```
library(microbenchmark)
m1 <- microbenchmark(
  by( df$speed, df$dive, mean),
  aggregate( speed ~ dive, df, mean ),
  splitmean(df),
  ddply( df, .(dive), function(x) mean(x$speed) ),
  dcast( melt(df), variable ~ dive, mean),
  dt[, mean(speed), by = dive],
  summarize( group_by(df, dive), m = mean(speed) ),
  summarize( group_by(dt, dive), m = mean(speed) )
)

> print(m1, signif = 3)
Unit: microseconds
                                           expr  min   lq   mean median   uq  max neval      cld
                    by(df$speed, df$dive, mean)  302  325  343.9    342  362  396   100  b      
              aggregate(speed ~ dive, df, mean)  904  966 1012.1   1020 1060 1130   100     e   
                                  splitmean(df)  191  206  249.9    220  232 1670   100 a       
  ddply(df, .(dive), function(x) mean(x$speed)) 1220 1310 1358.1   1340 1380 2740   100      f  
         dcast(melt(df), variable ~ dive, mean) 2150 2330 2440.7   2430 2490 4010   100        h
                   dt[, mean(speed), by = dive]  599  629  667.1    659  704  771   100   c     
 summarize(group_by(df, dive), m = mean(speed))  663  710  774.6    744  782 2140   100    d    
 summarize(group_by(dt, dive), m = mean(speed)) 1860 1960 2051.0   2020 2090 3430   100       g 

autoplot(m1)
```

[image: benchmark 10 rows]

As usual, `data.table` has a little more overhead so comes in about average for small datasets.  These are microseconds, though, so the differences are trivial.  Any of the approaches works fine here, and you should choose based on:

- What you're already familiar with or want to be familiar with (`plyr` is always worth learning for its flexibility; `data.table` is worth learning if you plan to analyze huge datasets; `by` and `aggregate` and `split` are all base R functions and thus universally available)
- What output it returns (numeric, data.frame, or data.table -- the latter of which inherits from data.frame)

#### 10 million rows, 10 groups

But what if we have a big dataset?  Let's try 10^7 rows split over ten groups.

```
df <- data.frame(dive=factor(sample(letters[1:10],10^7,replace=TRUE)),speed=runif(10^7))
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt,dive)

m2 <- microbenchmark(
  by( df$speed, df$dive, mean),
  aggregate( speed ~ dive, df, mean ),
  splitmean(df),
  ddply( df, .(dive), function(x) mean(x$speed) ),
  dcast( melt(df), variable ~ dive, mean),
  dt[,mean(speed),by=dive],
  times=2
)

> print(m2, signif = 3)
Unit: milliseconds
                                           expr   min    lq    mean median    uq   max neval      cld
                    by(df$speed, df$dive, mean)   720   770   799.1    791   816   958   100    d    
              aggregate(speed ~ dive, df, mean) 10900 11000 11027.0  11000 11100 11300   100        h
                                  splitmean(df)   974  1040  1074.1   1060  1100  1280   100     e   
  ddply(df, .(dive), function(x) mean(x$speed))  1050  1080  1110.4   1100  1130  1260   100      f  
         dcast(melt(df), variable ~ dive, mean)  2360  2450  2492.8   2490  2520  2620   100       g 
                   dt[, mean(speed), by = dive]   119   120   126.2    120   122   212   100 a       
 summarize(group_by(df, dive), m = mean(speed))   517   521   531.0    522   532   620   100   c     
 summarize(group_by(dt, dive), m = mean(speed))   154   155   174.0    156   189   321   100  b      

autoplot(m2)
```

[image: benchmark 1e7 rows, 10 groups]

Then `data.table` or `dplyr` using operating on `data.table`s is clearly the way to go. Certain approaches (`aggregate` and `dcast`) are beginning to look very slow.

#### 10 million rows, 1,000 groups

If you have more groups, the difference becomes more pronounced.  With **1,000 groups** and the same 10^7 rows:

```
df <- data.frame(dive=factor(sample(seq(1000),10^7,replace=TRUE)),speed=runif(10^7))
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt,dive)

# then run the same microbenchmark as above
print(m3, signif = 3)
Unit: milliseconds
                                           expr   min    lq    mean median    uq   max neval    cld
                    by(df$speed, df$dive, mean)   776   791   816.2    810   828   925   100  b    
              aggregate(speed ~ dive, df, mean) 11200 11400 11460.2  11400 11500 12000   100      f
                                  splitmean(df)  5940  6450  7562.4   7470  8370 11200   100     e 
  ddply(df, .(dive), function(x) mean(x$speed))  1220  1250  1279.1   1280  1300  1440   100   c   
         dcast(melt(df), variable ~ dive, mean)  2110  2190  2267.8   2250  2290  2750   100    d  
                   dt[, mean(speed), by = dive]   110   111   113.5    111   113   143   100 a     
 summarize(group_by(df, dive), m = mean(speed))   625   630   637.1    633   644   701   100  b    
 summarize(group_by(dt, dive), m = mean(speed))   129   130   137.3    131   142   213   100 a     

autoplot(m3)
```

[image]

So `data.table` continues scaling well, and `dplyr` operating on a `data.table` also works well, with `dplyr` on `data.frame` close to an order of magnitude slower.  The `split`/`sapply` strategy seems to scale poorly in the number of groups (meaning the `split()` is likely slow and the `sapply` is fast).  `by` continues to be relatively efficient--at 5 seconds, it's definitely noticeable to the user but for a dataset this large still not unreasonable.  Still, if you're routinely working with datasets of this size, `data.table` is clearly the way to go - 100% data.table for the best performance or `dplyr` with `dplyr` using `data.table` as a viable alternative.

Comment: Wow...thankyou very much this is a huge help. The aggregate function works perfectly and the microbenchmark library looks very good for my plots. Thanks again!

Comment: which library do I need for the    splitmean function?

Comment: `split` and `sapply` are both part of base R, so you just need to define that function (copy/paste it in to an active R session) and it will work.

Comment: Also, the `microbenchmark` package benchmarks things.  It's `ggplot2` which is actually making the plot there (and it's a great package).

Comment: Ari, which version of `data.table` is that with please? It's testing `mean` in `j` which has had a major speed improvement in v1.8.2. Wiki point 3 is no longer needed to know. But since the benchmark tests just 2 groups, iiuc, that won't make a difference here. If you increase the number of groups, then, we might be talking significant differences (in units of seconds or minutes).

Comment: Also Ari, why are you concerned with differences in microseconds and milliseconds. The benchmark in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533438/why-is-plyr-so-slow) seems to be more relevant. It's useful to see sessionInfo(), too.

Comment: Ah, @MatthewDowle, never happy just being an order of magnitude or two faster than the competition are we?  :-)  Just updated to 1.8.2  Didn't affect the first set of results.  I updated the second set of results with a bigger (both in nrow and in the number of groups) dataset.

Comment: Nope, never happy! Although 13 secs down to 0.1 secs is an order of magnitude, it's the 13 seconds that also matters. 13 secs just isn't significant to many people, myself included sometimes. So the next fastest at 1.1 second looks really pretty good in this set of choices. The difference between 1.1 and 0.1 is definitely insignificant for many. I care about the absolute time of the next fastest, for that reason. So I'd be happier with 100, 1000 or 10,000 groups (rather than 10). I'm wondering also actually - where is `splitmean`?

Comment: Just added a benchmark in [@Joran's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446254/how-to-emulate-sql-partition-by-in-r) that is my idea of significant differences, on far fewer rows.

Comment: @MatthewDowle So it shall be written, so it shall be done. :-)  `splitmean` is defined in my answer above...it's just `split()` followed by an `sapply` of `mean`.  I could probably make it a little faster using `vapply`.

Comment: +10 Ok great. That's more like it with 1000 groups. Many thanks for adding that. I'm on holiday for next 2 weeks so you can have a nice break from my bugging, you'll be relieved to hear :-)

Comment: Haha.  Always enjoy your comments.  Keep 'em coming.

Comment: See also this post for a thorough review of base R *apply commands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega/7141669#7141669

Comment: @AriB.Friedman I reran everything to include `dplyr` in the benchmarks and plots. I also added some `dplyr` commentary trying to stay in the spirit of your answer, but please make any adjustments - it is after all, **your** answer :)

Comment: @Gregor Nice! Thanks very much.  Looks beautiful, and it was long overdue for a `dplyr` update. Double kudos for showing `dplyr` with/without `data.table`.

Comment: Holy smack. What an excellent, precise, and comprehensive answers. Kudos.

Answer (score 11):

**2015 update with dplyr:**

```
df %>% group_by(dive) %>% summarise(percentage = mean(speed))
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

   dive percentage
1 dive1  0.4777462
2 dive2  0.6726483
```

Answer (score 10):

```
aggregate(speed~dive,data=df,FUN=mean)
   dive     speed
1 dive1 0.7059729
2 dive2 0.5473777
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding alternative base R approach, which remains fast under various cases.

```
rowsummean <- function(df) {
  rowsum(df$speed, df$dive) / tabulate(df$dive)
}
```

Borrowing the benchmarks from @Ari:

**10 rows, 2 groups**

[image: res1]

**10 million rows, 10 groups**

[image: res2]

**10 million rows, 1000 groups**

[image: res3]

Answer (score 3):

With the new funtion `across`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(dive) %>% 
  summarise(across(speed, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

We already have tons of options to get mean by group, adding one more from `mosaic` package.

```
mosaic::mean(speed~dive, data = df)
#dive1 dive2 
#0.579 0.440
```

This returns a named numeric vector, if needed a dataframe we can wrap it in `stack`

```
stack(mosaic::mean(speed~dive, data = df))

#  values   ind
#1  0.579 dive1
#2  0.440 dive2
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(dive=factor(sample(c("dive1","dive2"),10,replace=TRUE)),
                 speed=runif(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
   fgroup_by(dive) %>%
   fsummarise(speed = fmean(speed))
#   dive     speed
#1 dive1 0.5788479
#2 dive2 0.4401514
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(dive=factor(sample(c("dive1","dive2"),10,replace=TRUE)),
             speed=runif(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending answer provided by RCchelsie - If anyone wants to get mean calculate by group for all columns in the dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(dive) %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols=everything(), mean, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr `1.1.0` (and above) we can temporarily group using the `.by` argument.

This makes the code shorter (as we avoid `group_by` and `ungroup` statements) and `.by` always returns an ungrouped dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise(speed = mean(speed), .by = dive)

#   dive     speed
#1 dive1 0.5788479
#2 dive2 0.4401514
```

Answer (score 0):

With `timeplyr` you can have your cake and eat it too.

And by cake I mean `tidy` syntax and by eat it I mean the cake is super fast.

`stat_summarise()` uses a mix of `collapse`, `data.table` and `dplyr` to achieve optimal performance without sacrificing `tidy` syntax.

Comparing the most efficient method using `data.table` to the timeplyr equivalent, we can see comparable speeds.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(timeplyr)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(dive = factor(sample.int(10^6, size = 10^7, replace=TRUE)),
                 speed = runif(10^7))
setkey(dt, dive)

m2 <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dt[,mean(speed),by=dive],
  stat_summarise(dt, .cols = "speed", 
                 .by = dive, stat = "mean", sort = F),
  times = 15
)

print(m2, signif = 3)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                                           expr
#>                                                   dt[, mean(speed), by = dive]
#>  stat_summarise(dt, .cols = "speed", .by = dive, stat = "mean",      sort = F)
#>  min  lq mean median  uq max neval cld
#>  148 184  272    261 344 499    15   a
#>  139 197  283    221 328 540    15   a
autoplot(m2)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will
#> replace the existing one.
```

## 10 million rows, ~ 1 million groups

[image]

When comparing memory usage, `stat_summarise()` is actually far more efficient than `data.table`.

```r
# Memory comparison
bench::mark(
  DT = dt[, list(speed = mean(speed)), by = dive],
  TP = stat_summarise(dt, .cols = "speed", 
                 .by = dive, stat = "mean", sort = F),
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 DT            194ms    308ms      3.25     248MB     4.87
#> 2 TP            133ms    277ms      3.61    68.7MB     1.81
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>