# lag function in data.tables in R

Tags: r, data.table, lag

Given below is my dataset.
I am using lag function to shift rows by 1 and 2 numbers.But it is not doing it
Dataset

```
structure(list(var_1 = 1:10, var_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), var_3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("var_1", 
"var_2", "var_3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000320788>)
```

Command used for lagging

```
dat[,lagged:=lag(var_1,-1,na.pad=TRUE)]
```

I was using the solution given on the below link  [Basic lag in R vector/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558988/basic-lag-in-r-vector-dataframe)

Comment: Do you want `dat[, lagged := c(NA, head(var_1, -1))]`?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicated of this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11448652/176995