# Speed up 3-column R search in large data.frame

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

Alright. I've heavily edited this question to a) make it make more sense, and b) reflect where I'm at with the problem.

I have two data sets -- let's call them set1 and set2 -- each of about 6 million rows. Currently, I have them loaded into R as data.tables.

```
>set1<-data.table(read.csv('~/file1.csv', stringsAsFactors=F))
>setkey(set1, id1)
>head(set1)
     id1 start_unixtime end_unixtime seconds_diff        id2
1:  1674     1354741858   1354741858            0  227167461
2:  1674     1354752386   1354752951          565  227246263
3:  1674     1354764412   1354764412            0  227358796
4:  1674     1354773044   1354773776          732  227421295
5:  1674     1354778651   1354778651            0  227448774
6:  1674     1354810424   1354810424            0  227631113
>set2<-data.table(read.csv('~/file2.csv', stringsAsFactors=F))
>setkey(set2, id1)
>head(set2)
     id1    unix_timestamp event_name
1:  1674    1355202784           join
2:  1674    1354351118           join
3:  1674    1354349648           play
4:  1674    1354780517           join
5:  1674    1355278891           join
6:  1674    1354617262           join
```

One problematic detail to point out: set2 has no unique keys. Only the tuple of each row is actually unique. In set1, id2 is unique. Fun times!

The operation I'm performing goes like this: for every row in `set2`, I need to take the unix_timestamp, find the row in `set1` where `start_unixtimestamp <= unix_timestamp <= end_unixtimestamp` and id1 matches, then assign the corresponding `set1.id2` to the appropriate row in `set2`. Every row in `set2` has an entry in `set1`, but not every row in `set1` has an entry in `set2`. One `id2` can be assigned to many rows in `set2`. What I need to wind up with is this (NOTE: the following data is fake, as I haven't been able to produce any actual success yet.):

```
>head(set2)
     id1    unix_timestamp event_name         id2
1:  1674        1355202784       join   227167461
2:  1674        1354351118       join   227157309
3:  1674        1354349648       play   227157309
4:  1674        1354780517       join   227157309
5:  1674        1355278891       join   271089456
6:  1674        1354617262       join   221729485
```

Here is a *mess* of data table I've cooked up:

```
set2[, id2 := set1[set2[, id1], list(start_unixtime, end_unixtime, id2)][(start_unixtime <= unix_timestamp & unix_timestamp <= end_unixtime), id2, by=id2]][, list(id2)][, id2:= id2]
```

To talk through what I understand to be going on:

1. `set2` calls the assignment operator `:=`
2. The right hand side invokes `set1`, which starts by `joining` id1 rows from set2.
3. The columns `start_unixtime`, `end_unixtime`, and `id2` are selected.
4. From that result, a second set of selections are done, which gets `id2` where the `utc_timestamp` of `id2` is between `start_unixtime` and `end_unixtime`.
5. ...and here, I think I'm doing something badly wrong -- because at this step, I always seem to have two columns, each labeled `id2` and containing identical results. So, I select one column...
6. ...and specify it for assignment. (I do not know why this is done twice. I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705488/using-data-table-i-and-j-arguments-in-functions?rq=1), which uses this second `:=`, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703299/r-using-data-table-operations-to-calculate-new-columns?rq=1) which does not, and I have simply no idea why.

...which does not work. @mnel has proposed something like:

```
set2[set1, nomatch=0][unix_timestamp %between c(start_unixtime, end_unixtime, incbounds=T)]
```

...which works when I try it with his test data, but not with my data. It occurs to me that my data might be of some type (character?) which `data.table` (or R period) might not be coercing properly? I might be dense, but I can't seem to figure out how to call `as.integer()` on a specified column of a `data.table`.

**Edit**: yeah, my data was all character, and I forgot that `data.table` inherits from `data.frame`. So, a little `set1$start_unixtime <- as.integer($set1$start_unixtime)` and at least I'm sure everything is all integers. However, when I run that command, I still get this:

```
>head(set2)
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 8 cols: id1,utc_timestamp,event_name,start_unixtime,end_unixtime,seconds_diff...
```

**Addition**
Here are snippets of my actual data:

```
set1 <-  as.data.table(list(id1 = c(1674L, 1674L, 1674L, 1674L, 1674L, 1674L), 
     start_unixtime = c(1354741858L, 1354752386L, 1354764412L, 1354773044L, 1354778651L, 1354810424L), 
     end_unixtime = c(1354741858L, 1354752951L, 1354764412L, 1354773776L, 1354778651L, 1354810424L), 
    seconds_diff = c(0L, 565L, 0L, 732L, 0L, 0L), 
    id2 = c(227167461L, 227246263L, 227358796L, 227421295L, 227448774L, 227631113L))
set2 <- as.data.table(list(
    id1 = c(1674L, 1674L, 1674L, 1674L, 1674L, 1674L), 
    utc_timestamp = c(1354752431L, 1354780517L, 1354811978L, 1354824385L, 1354833271L, 1354862753L), 
    event_name = c("joinRegularTable_2", "joinRegularTable_2", "joinRegularTable_2", "joinRegularTable_2","joinRegularTable_2", "joinRegularTable_2"))
```

Comment: `data.table` is the answer.

Comment: Just came across that -- thanks!

Comment: if you know sql, [try monetdb](http://www.asdfree.com/2012/11/why-and-how-to-install-monetdb-with-r.html)

Comment: Does each `id1` value appear only once in each dataset?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: I do know sql, thanks! I'll give that a look.

Comment: @James: I've updated my question to better address that, but: no. In set1, only id2 is unique. In set2, only the tuple of the row is unique.

Comment: Where does `utc_timestamp` come from? Should the first column in `set2` be called this?

Comment: Oh jeeze. Yes. Thank you -- that's a column name from a different dataset entirely...

Comment: Post examples of the data you have. dput(head(set1)) and dput(head(set2))

Comment: Cool. n00b best practices question: is posting that kind of data example commonly good form in R Stack Overflow posts? I don't think I've seen that before, but I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Yes -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: OH MAN. Thanks! I'ma go memorize that now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21352/discussion-between-mnel-and-gastove)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this will work on your data as you perhaps need to post a more complete example, but something like the following might work. It does 1 join (binary search) then one vector scan (which creates a couple of long logical vectors behind the scenes, so is not ideal)

I've provided a simple but larger example data set with a bit more replication.

```
DT <- as.data.table(list(id1 = c(5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L), 
    id2 = 1:10, startunix = 1:10, endunix = 5:14))

DA <- as.data.table(list(id1 = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), unixtime = c(5L, 1L, 6L, 12L)))

setkey(DA,id1)
setkey(DT,id1)


DT[DA, nomatch=0][unixtime %between% c(startunix, endunix)]

   id1 id2 startunix endunix unixtime
1:   5   1         1       5        6
2:   5   3         3       7        6
3:   5   5         5       9        6
4:   5   7         7      11        6
```

To explain what it is doing, it is matching by `id1`,  and `nomatch = 0` means that these are not included. This expands to all combinations of the multiple rows in DA[J(5)] and DT[J(5)] - in this case there

```
 DA[J(5)]
   id1 unixtime
1:   5        1
2:   5        6
3:   5       12
> DT[J(5)]
   id1 id2 startunix endunix
1:   5   1         1       5
2:   5   3         3       7
3:   5   5         5       9
4:   5   7         7      11
```

So the created merged data set contains all 12 combinations. ( 4 times 3)

I then use the function `between` ( part of the `data.table` package) to subset those values where `unixtime` is  between `startunix` and `endunix`.

To the best of my knowledge you won't be able to use binary searches to find whether something is within a range (however @MatthewDowle, the main `data.table` package author is active on SO and may jump in here with a comment as to whether this is possible or likely in the future)

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for drawing my attention to `%between%` -- I hadn't found that yet. And thanks for the answer! Interestingly enough, I cannot get your code to work with my datasets, which seems to suggest my integers... well, aren't. I'm going to mess with that, and will report back (and maybe clean up my question a little...)

Comment: Yup, would be nice to do between joins in future ([FR203](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=203)). Can be done now (manually) using a `roll` join to the start with `which=TRUE`, then another `roll` join to the end again with `which=TRUE`, followed by a `seq` or `vecseq` with `+/-1` as appropriate. That's likely much faster than the `%between%` vector scan.

Comment: ....uh, huh. Okay. I've found the documentation on `roll` and `which`; I think I see what's going on there. Are you proposing those as modifications to the monstrous command I cooked up, or the somewhat more elegant one @mnel created? Also... I confess that I don't follow what `seq` or `vecseq` get you.